# Merging two projects into one - Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a project (Web Application) which I have been developing in C#/ASP.NET, and I'm required to take another project and essentially merge it into mine, so they can share sessions etc. This project is coded in VB.NET, and I think may be a 'web site' - it utilizes the App_Code folder, which I don't have.

I basically want to create a folder in my project, and copy all the files of the other project into here, but it's proving very difficult. When I add in the folder and use 'add existing' to add the other project files, the files don't seem to build, as I get all sorts of 'could not load type' errors.

Is there a certain way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. You can only convert one of the projects to suit the other. You can convert the VB code to C# code or the other way round. Another way out is to work out of Visual Studio such that, you will   make your builds against "csc" and you will likely need to write a Nant script to automate that process. Because, visual studio projects are tagged at a particular language run-time at a time.

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Hmm ok - in that case, is there any elegant way to pass some sessions to another web application? As they will login using my screen, and ideally they can avoid logging in when going to the other